# Working with large requests responses (JSON array of objects) in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, python-requests

I have spent the last couple of days combing through all the SO threads I could find, attempting different solutions, using different packages....and I've effectively gotten nowhere.  --Which makes me think I'm going about this in the wrong way.

I am hitting an API and getting a large response. (A response that will grow in size over time.) - Currently if I save the response as a file, it is 250mb. (Streaming with chunks - described below)

The response is structured as a **1 line** JSON array with repeating sets of objects with the same names. There are currently 100k sets, but will continue to grow.

Short Example:

```
[
    {
        "OBJ1": {
            "VALUE1": "1",
            "VALUE2": " "
        },
        "OBJ2": {
            "VALUE1": "Active"
        },
        "OBJ3": {
            "VALUE1": 0
        },
        "OBJ4": {
            "VALUE1": "1",
            "VALUE2": "er1128",
            "VALUE3": "er",
            "VALUE4": "ering Group",
            "VALUE5": "",
            "VALUE6": "1128",
            "VALUE7": "3599"
        },
        "OBJ5": {
            "VALUE1": 3,
            "VALUE2": "Group1"
        },
        "OBJ6": {
            "VALUE1": null
        }
    },
    {
        "OBJ1": {
            "VALUE1": "2",
            "VALUE2": " "
        },
        "OBJ2": {
            "VALUE1": "Active"
        },
        "OBJ3": {
            "VALUE1": 0
        },
        "OBJ4": {
            "VALUE1": "2",
            "VALUE2": "er1285P",
            "VALUE3": "er",
            "VALUE4": "ering Group",
            "VALUE5": "",
            "VALUE6": "1285P",
            "VALUE7": "3592"
        },
        "OBJ5": {
            "VALUE1": 3,
            "VALUE2": "Group1"
        },
        "OBJ6": {
            "VALUE1": null
        }
    }
]
```

When my file size was smaller, I used json.loads to read in the response directly, and then I looped through pulling out the data I needed (50+ values) and appending to a list. After that, I turn it into a data frame for further processing with functions.

```
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df=json.loads(data.content)

List =[]
for i in df:
    List.append([i['OBJ1']['VALUE1'],i['OBJ3']['VALUE1'],i['OBJ4']['VALUE3']])

finalDF = pd.DataFrame(List, columns=['Thing1', 'Thing2', 'Thing3'])
```

And that worked great....until I got to around 50k sets of OBJ1-OBJ6. In which case json.loads starts barfing with MemoryErrors.

Currently I am only working with Python 32bit. (Restricted environment that I don't have control of.)

So I began with trying to figure out if I could stream the response somehow...which got me nowhere, likely because the response is one line?

I did however after many attempts figure out a way to save the response to a file:

```
local_filename = 'json_download.json'

    with requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
                f.write(chunk)
```

Which seems to work. (I can't open it in Notepad++ due to the size, but importing into excel as a JSON lets me traverse the structure and see that all the data is there.)

From here, I can't successfully bring the data back into python. I've tried various open/load/parse methods, all with memory errors.

Which makes me think I just can't go about this with a large dataframe?  So likely my functions will all have to be re-written to do this differently?

(Currently I am creating reports that search every value and list out counts on missing values, where emails or phone numbers exist, where non-ascii characters exist...etc. Just QC'ing the entire data set and providing indicators where problems exist.)

So the crux of my question... Is there a way to get this type and size of data back into a dataframe so I can use my functions as written?  If not, how do I go about dealing with this dataset so I can run these reports?

Comment: Did you look into streaming parsers?

Comment: Currently looking at/trying NAYA

Comment: @quamrana Attempting to use naya both on the request as well as the upload of the saved version. Neither is working.  And I currently can't get ijson to work due to my restrictive environment.